# Check if one row of json data exist in React Native

Tags: json, react-native, expo

I am creating a ticket scanner app with expo React Native.

When I scan a qr code I have a var called ScannedCode.

When I render the jsonData in the app the output is:

{"txid":"ch_3LZwATA4WCavBwXA1iN5diTN"}{"txid":"ch_3LZwBNA4WCavBwXA0kPBItB3"}{"txid":"ch_3LZwEkA4WCavBwXA02WfrvTP"}{"txid":"ch_3LZwFMA4WCavBwXA0xaSxBTv"}

I use an if statement to check if the ticket (txid) is valid.
So I want it to be something like this:

if (ScannedCode === jsonData) {Ticket is valid}
else {not valid]
My problem is the if statment dont check each json data.

I want it to check if "one of the" json txid exist {ticket is valid}

In my code below I believe the IF statement check if the scanned code is equal to the total json data.
Because in the screenshot of the app, I scanned a code that existed in the jsonData, but the output was a red button that said not valid. It should be green and say valid.

Any suggestion?

```
  var TicketStatus= "No status"
  var StatusColor = "#000000"
  var ScannedCode = ScannedWithCamera;
//var jsonData= "ch_3LZwFMA4WCavBwXA0xaSxBTv";
  
    var jsonData = data.map((txid) => {

    return (
      JSON.stringify({ ...txid})
    )
  })



  if (ScannedCode === jsonData) {
    TicketStatus = "VALID"
    StatusColor = "green"
  } else if (ScannedCode === "") {
    TicketStatus = ""
  } else {
    TicketStatus = "NOT VALID"
    StatusColor = "RED"
  }
```

[image: JSON-data from website]

[image: Screenshot of the App]

Comment: Maybe use `array.every(item=>if statement here)` This allows you to apply a conditional to every item in an array

Comment: Instead of this code?
```var jsonData = dator.map((TicketID) => {
    return (
      JSON.stringify({ ...TicketID })
    )
  })``` @BrandonPiña

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
if (data.some(function(e){ return e.txid=== ScannedCode})) {
    BillettStatus = "GYLDIG"
    StatusColor = "#008000"
  } else if (ScannedCode === "") {
    BillettStatus = ""
  } else {
    BillettStatus = "IKKE GYLDIG"
    StatusColor = "#FF0000"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

'jsonData' receives an Array because the map always returns an array.

you can fetch txid like this:

```
const jsonScannedCode = jsonData[0]?.txid
//jsonScannedCode will have id or it will be undefined
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).